# Can't import linreg in Jupiter

Tags: python, jupyter

I recently started teaching myself data analysis and was trying to replicate Python code on my Mac Book. I entered the following into Jupyter:

```
%pylab inline
import linreg
import pandas as
```

However, I got the following error message:

```
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-be04d91f348a> in <module>()
  1 get_ipython().magic(u'pylab inline')
----> 2 import linreg
  3 import pandas as pd

ImportError: No module named linreg
```

After an extensive Google search, I have found no instances of such an import error. Is there something wrong with the code? If not, how can I add the linreg module to Jupyter? I copied the code from the website below.

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/nborwankar/LearnDataScience/blob/master/notebooks/WA1.%20Linear%20Regression%20Overview%20Worksheet.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

The instruction "import linreg" imports another Python file as module from the current directory of the file you are running in Jupyter.

That means that the worksheet you are trying to replicate doesn't work on its own, but requires the module linreg to run. The module is provided by file linreg.py, you can find it located in the "notebooks" folder of your worksheet exercise:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/nborwankar/LearnDataScience/tree/master/notebooks/

What I suggest you should do to run the examples locally is copy all the worksheet files located at https://github.com/nborwankar/LearnDataScience to your machine and start from there. That will give you the proper folder structure so that all the worksheets can find their dependencies. Follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient reply. I just downloaded all the files on my desktop, and I also click the "upload" button on the Jupiter to upload "Learn Data Science" file. I even downloaded the "linreg.py" file separately on the desktop. I'm very puzzled about whether I copied the worksheets files I needed to my machine in a right way. Because after running the first line code, the second line code"linreg.lab_expriment()" couldn't execute the same result.I already met such similar situations several times, so I really want to figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the github repo. linreg.py is a helper module.

Github repo: 
https://github.com/nborwankar/LearnDataScience

https://github.com/nborwankar/LearnDataScience/blob/master/notebooks/linreg.py

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient reply. I just downloaded all the files on my desktop, and I also click the "upload" button on the Jupiter to upload "Learn Data Science" file. I even downloaded the "linreg.py" file separately on the desktop. I'm very puzzled about whether I copied the worksheets files I needed to my machine in a right way. Because after running the first line code, the second line code"linreg.lab_expriment()" couldn't execute the same result.I already met such similar situations several times, so I really want to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: After downloading the repo.  Unzip it, where-ever. Open a terminal in unzipped file directory.. Within the terminal, type ipython notebook. This should launch ipython in  your browser. ... You may need to google how to use ipython notebook, as that is outside the scope of SO.

Comment: But after downloading the files to my desktop, the file "LearnDataScience-master" is already unzipped. I don't need to zip it. So I type the code "LearnDataScience-master test.zip" on the terminal, the terminal output "LearnDataScience-master: command not found " . So so so sorry to disturb you again.